# in JSOM page getting Page unresponsive

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-jsom

I have developed a jsom page where once we submit data it get save to an custom list(10 columns). When submitting minimum 50 items and can have maximum of 150 items will be save to the list. the problem is that I'm getting Page unresponsive alert and page freezes till the process gets completed.

Please suggest how to avoid this un-responsive issue in the browsers

Comment: Please share your code. It is difficult to comment anything without looking at you r code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get better answers if you post your code as well.

But it sounds like you are using "ExecuteQuery()" which waits for Sharepoint to respond.

You should use "ExecuteQueryAsync()" which uses asynchronous call in which code continues to execute and does not wait for SharePoint’s response.